# POST json data to Bottle

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, json, bottle

I am a newbie to Bottle and sort of to Python as well and I am trying create an app whenever I click a button, an AJAX is fired and POST a json to server and store it using SQLite.

However, at current stage, I am trying to figure out how do I successfully received the data in the server.

On the client side,
I have the following send_data function written in JavaScript.

```
function send_data(feedback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/feedback",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(feedback),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function() {
            alert("Feedback successfully stored in the server!");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Feedback failed to store back in the server!");
        },          

}
```

The passed in parameter `feedback` looks something like `{"id1": 1, "id2": 2}`.

On the server side, I have a `feedback.py` file and the code is

```
from bottle import request, route, run
@route('/feedback', method='POST')

def feedback():
    comments = request.json
    print comments

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Right now, I just want to check if I have received the data successful. But everytime, when I click that botton, I receive the following error

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/feedback. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

`OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/feedback [HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed 2ms]`

I am not sure if it's because I am not using the element `<form>`. That botton is technically just an image. Every time I click that image, `send_data()` function is fired.

Anyone can help? I really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: using a form content type will make it easier. or just don't specify one. or make your python server honor OPTIONS requests.

Comment: Hi, may I ask how do I make the server honor OPTIONS request? Do I change method='POST' to method='OPTIONS'? Sorry, I am quite a newbie...

Comment: the form still uses POST, OPTIONS is sent internally by the browser for non-standard form types to ensure CORS capabilities. you can post without CORS using a normal form tag, but you can't get feedback from it. readup on "enabling cors"; there's a lot out there, and i don't know enough python to code an OPTION handler (though it's fairly simple i'm sure)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a direction for me :). I am going to try that.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0):

Cross Origins Requests are restricted as a security measure by the browser. It is possible to overcome that by setting an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. You can can use [bottle-cors](https://pypi.org/project/bottle-cors/) or create a decorator like the following on your server code (Python/bottle):

```
def enable_cors(fn):
  def _enable_cors(*args, **kwargs):
      response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS'
      response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token'

      if request.method != 'OPTIONS':
          # actual request; reply with the actual response
          return fn(*args, **kwargs)

  return _enable_cors
```

and then with your example:

```
from bottle import request, route, run
@enable_cors
@route('/feedback', method='POST')

def feedback():
    comments = request.json
    print comments

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Note that it's best to allow specific origins instead of using `*`.

You can read more about Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Answer (score -1):

You can make this work by disabling the Cross-origin restrictions.

On safari, open the Develop panel, and check disable cross-origin restrictions, or use a browser like Firefox.